How to load landscape far away in the level, while not loading things I shouldn't be able to see?
My landscape is invisible after a certain distance away from the player when I use world partition in Unreal Engine 5.4. How can I make it so that the landscape is visible when it should be visible to the player but it is not loaded when the player shouldn't be able to see it?
For example, if the landscape is behind a forest, and no part of the landscape should be visible to the player, it should not be loaded. But when I go on top of a mountain, I should be able to see the entire landscape, without some parts not loading.
Occlusion Culling works by default, and I've just set the distance culling high enough so that I can see the whole landscape at once. Now I'm trying to figure out if I should use Nanite on my landscape, and if not, how to create Landscape LODs
